# how to force yes when using preupg

Tags: linux, centos, redhat

I installed the 'preupg' command using:

```
yum -y install redhat-upgrade-tool preupgrade-assistant-contents
```

And I want to run the following command:

```
preupg
```

It asks if I want to continue, but I am using docker and cant say yes or no so it exits. Is there a way to silence this command?

I have tried -f and -q

Comment: For anyone else that has this problem, you have to use the flag --force. 

-f doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

To run the "preupg" tool without user interaction use

**preupg --force** 
this will not ask for permissions and assume yes for every question.
As the preupg man page says

--force
 Suppress user interaction.